# How to create a valid factory with a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have been trying to get this to work looking at the [official documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations), [this blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/aint-no-calla-back-girl) and have looked at examples on here. Whatever I try I get errors.

I am looking for a working example to see how the test is structured; I am using Factory Girl 4.4.1 and Rspec 3.

The only way I have managed to create a valid object is by doing this, but it's not the correct way to build my object as I want to still run validation on the animal model first and then animal_image.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :animal_image do
   animal_id 1
   image { File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/yp2.jpg") }
 end 
end

file = FactoryGirl.create(:animal_image)
#<AnimalImage id: 101, animal_id: 1, image: "yp2.jpg", created_at: "2014-10-14 10:08:55", updated_at: "2014-10-14 10:08:55">
```

My models

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :animal_images, dependent: :destroy
end

class AnimalImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :animal do

    ignore do
      images_count 5
    end

    after(:create) do |animal, evaluator|
      create_list(:animal_image, evaluator.images_count, animal: animal)
    end

  end 
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :animal_image do

    image { File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/yp2.jpg") }

  end 
end

a = FactoryGirl.create(:animal)
a.animal_images.count
=> 5

a = FactoryGirl.create(:animal, images_count: 1)
a.animal_images.count
=> 1
```

More information [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations)

Comment: thanks, i was trying the official factory_girl docs and they have `transient do posts_count 5 end`, where as in your example we are ignoring this? whats the difference ?

Comment: they must have rename `ignore` in `transient` but the idea is the same. It's an attribute ignored when building the instance of your class.

Comment: well your example is working (so glad), thank you so much.. my attempt was failing on images_count..

Comment: you welcome, edited the transient thing, thank you, i've learn something too.

Comment: ah, sorry for any confusion, but `ignore` works, `transient` throws undefined method `images_count', so using ignore is better from what i can tell